# Why can function pointers or lambda expressions be used instead of hash functions in templates of unordered containers?

Tags: c++, hash, std

The following examples are mentioned in 11.4 of <<C + + primer 5th>>:

```
size_t hasher(const sales_data &sd)
{
    return hash<string>(0)(sd.isbn());
}
bool eqOp(const sales_data &lhs,const sales_data &rhs){
    return lhs.isbn() == rhs.isbn ();
}
```

Then create the following `unordered_multiset` container:

```
using SD_multiset = unordered_multiset<sales_data,
                    decltype(hasher)* , decltype(eqOp)*>;  // why it can?
SD_multiset bookstore(42, hasher, eqOp);
```

Isn't `std:hash` a function object? Why can a function pointer or lambda expression be accepted

Comment: Anything that can be called is accepted.

Comment: perhaps not easy to read, but this may help to understand what is considered a "callable" https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable. In a nutshell: anything that can be called

Comment: Is it because std::hash<Key> is a "callable"? So Can any "callable" replace it? @HolyBlackCat

Comment: @LandP any Callable which can be called with one parameter that can bind to `const Key &`, and return something that implicitly converts to `std::size_t`

Comment: @LandP also the result of a lambda expression is a function object